# Can anyone please help me, struggling to convert between quaternions and euler angles

Tags: python, rviz, ros-melodic, publisher, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight copy of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from math import sin
from math import cos

twist=Twist()
def callback(data):
    global twist
        twist=data
        print("value of twist cb is:",twist)
def move():
    rospy.init_node('move')
    rospy.Subscriber("cmd_vel",Twist,callback)
    pose_pub=rospy.Publisher("robo_pose",PoseStamped,queue_size=10)
    robo_pose=PoseStamped()
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        rate= rospy.Rate(10)
                robo_pose.pose.position.x+=((twist.linear.x*0.1)*cos(robo_pose.pose.orientation.z))+             ((twist.linear.y*0.1)*sin(robo_pose.pose.orientation.z))
        robo_pose.pose.position.y+=((twist.linear.y*0.1)*cos(robo_pose.pose.orientation.z))+((twist.linear.x*0.1)*sin(robo_pose.pose.orientation.z))
        robo_pose.pose.orientation.z+=(twist.angular.z*0.1)
        robo_pose.pose.orientation.normalize()
        robo_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
            robo_pose.header.frame_id="map"  
        pose_pub.publish(robo_pose)
        print("pose is:", robo_pose)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    move()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339762/can-anyone-please-help-me,-struggling-to-convert-between-quaternions--and-euler-angles./) by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from euler to quaternion:
q = quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)

from quarternion to euler angles:
roll, pitch, yaw = euler_from_quaternion(q)

do not forget to add includes and imports.

~best

-CA

---

Originally posted by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) with karma: 180 on 2019-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on 2019-12-12**:
Thanks a lot, it worked!

**Comment by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on 2019-12-12**:
if you think that the answer worked, could you click the mark this answer as correct button on the left side?